# File and folder permissions: You'll need to provide administrator permission to move this file

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, permissions, terminal-server

I have a Windows Server 2008 (Terminal Server) with one NTFS disk. I'm trying to give remote desktop users (local group containing an AD group) modify permissions for this drive (E:). I gave them modify rights but user tells me that he is still getting an error when moving a file:

```
You'll need to provide administrator permission to move this file
```

How to solve this?

Edit:

It seems that the permissions I gave in the drive level did not affect the permissions of the child objects (folders and files). How to set the inheritance?

Answer (score 3):

It's probably sust a permissions or ownership problem.

Right click on the folder and click on properties and add yourself as a permitted user with Full Rights.  Go to Advanced and do the same on that scren as well.  Then go to the Ownership Tab and take ownership of the folder.

If this doesn't work, you may need to do the same thing to the parent folder as well (and perhaps it's parent).

Eventually you should be able to get access and move the folder.